# grub hidden menu, like lilo did it

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, grub

In the old days of lilo we could set it to boot with timeout=0 but if shift was pressed at boot time the menu was displayed.

Can this be done with grub.

I am using grub 1.98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supposed to be the default behavior, but grub 2 is so buggy if you set timeout to 0 shift won't work, and if you set it to hidden it will either not hide at all, or shift won't work there either.